# I am trying to get my navigation to be on the right side of the page, currently it is in the middle

Tags: html, css, navigation

[image: css1 of 4] 
[image: css2of 4]
[image: css3 of 4]
[image: css4 of 4]
[image: snip]
I am trying to get my navigation to be on the right side of the page, currently it is in the middle. I have done something to the css and can't figure out what I did, now the navigation won't go back to the right side of the page, it is stuck in the middle.

```css
.sample-css{
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="container-logo">
            <div>
              <a name="top"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logofor Web1-01.png" alt="Morpheus Design Studios Logo" style="width: 149px; height: 100px;" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <div class="right-side">
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></div>
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper"><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></div>
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></div>
            <div class="nav-link-wrapper"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="conbtn">
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                  <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>

                  <div class="dropdown-content"><a href="graphicdesign.html">Graphic Design</a><a href="photography.html">Photography</a><a href="printing.html">Professional Printing</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It wont let me add my css in the snippet

Comment: Please see: [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TonyaJohnson i made changes update your snippet and your css code. Also add if external css using.

Comment: Thanks @charles, it was a lot of code to make work like I have it and stack overflow wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @TonyaJohnson just add navigation related html and css code.

Comment: added the pictures of the related css

Comment: @TonyaJohnson I think it's the `justify-content: center` declaration on the `.nav-wrapper` selector. You can change it to `justify-content: flex-end` to align it to the right side of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following:

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

to:

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Read more: [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) (MDN)

Comment: That was it !!! Thank you so much!!! I was thinking of that but didn't think it would work so I didn't even try it... I have learned my lesson. You are amazing!!!!